# How to germinate guava seeds?

Tags: germination, guavas

Recently I received guava seeds from two of my friends. One is a red variety and other is a normal Guava variety. I planted the seeds on coco-peat three weeks ago and kept watering since then. I just didn't plant the seeds deeper than one inch.  But still not a single seed germinated. What am I doing wrong here. Will it germinate or what's the correct way to germinate Guava seeds?

Answer (score 2):

Different people on the web recommend

- soaking the seed in water for 2 weeks before planting
- sandwiching the seed inside a damp folded paper towel, sealing it in a plastic bag, and hanging it up in direct sunlight till they germinate.
- putting the seed in boiling water for 5 minutes before planting to break the dormancy.

Whatever option you try, germination can take up to 8 weeks, and they need warmth to get them started. They are *tropical* plants after all. (But since your profile says "Sri Lanka", providing the warmth should not be a problem).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a parallel example you might find relevant to your situation - back in the Spring I ate a tangerine. There were about a dozen seeds. I set them aside thinking that I might get them to germinate. About 4 weeks later I potted them up in a general purpose mix and put the pot on top of my hot water tank to see what would happen. Two months later one came up. I emptied the pot and found all except the one just as they were when potted up. The one that germinated now has 6 leaves and looks good. I discarded the others.

Guava produces multiple small seeds in each fruit, so hopefully you had a good number to set to germinate. I have seen some references that recommend that citrus seeds be set to germinate immediately they leave the fruit, that is they not be allowed to dry out as mine were. That might not be relevant in your situation, but it's worth investigating. Key points I think are to increase your chances with many seeds and to be patient until one pops up.